# How can I update the WooCommerce cart and return new HTML in a single request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom "mini-cart" that has all the features of the main cart page, i.e. change quantity, remove item, enter coupon, remove coupon. I am presently listening for `change` on the cart `form` element and submitting it via Ajax (simplified below):

```
ajaxTask = $.post(
        $form.action, // this is a non-Ajax (front-end) URL, ie "/cart"
        $form.serialize()
    )
    .done(function(data,status,jqXHR){
        $cart.html(data);
    });
```

This triggers the normal WC form handler, as though the `update_cart` button were clicked (I added `<input type="hidden" name="update_cart" id="update_cart" value="1">` to the form to make this happen).

The trouble is, the ["update cart" action](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/556a238dfb02971dc59c0732ad0b72aa9fab6c18/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L552) has a built-in redirect which is supposed to reload the page. So the function above returns the entire page.

There is no other function that I know of that simply processes the form (whether it's changing a quantity, removing an item, adding an item, or applying a coupon) and exits. It seems hacky/dumb/bad practice to copy/paste most of the [form handler](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/556a238dfb02971dc59c0732ad0b72aa9fab6c18/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L552) into my own code just to avoid the redirect.

What I ***want*** the server to do is this:

```
static function ajax_update_cart() {
    // ( an action that updates the cart and outputs nothing )
    echo cart_html(); // output the custom cart HTML
    exit;
}
```

But I'm not seeing an obvious way. I do know about cart fragments but those entail a minimum of two round trips for the server. Is there a way to submit cart data, update the cart, and then return my own HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this I believe the following should work. Calls to wp_safe_redirect() will apply several filters: 'wp_safe_redirect_fallback', 'wp_redirect', 'wp_redirect_status', ... Any of these can be abused to prevent the HTTP redirect from happening and returning your own HTML.

```
add_filter('wp_safe_redirect_fallback', function($url) {
    if (/* wp_safe_redirect() is called from your cart update AJAX request */) {
        # Render your new cart HTML
        echo cart_html();
        # This filter cannot return otherwise wp_redirect() will be called!
        exit();
    }
    return $url;
}
```

N.B., The filter is not used as a filter but as a hook to changed the execution of wp_safe_redirect() to not do the HTTP redirect and return your generated HTML. I.e. the call to exit() is necessary!

ADDENDUM

I thought of another way to achieve this. Again it involves abusing a filter. In this case the filter 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated' will lie about the cart being updated preventing the call to wp_safe_redirect(). Then a lower priority action will generate the updated cart HTML.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', function($cart_updated) {
    if (/* filter 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated' is called from your cart update AJAX request */) {
        # returning false prevents the call to wp_safe_redirect()
        return false;
    }
    return $cart_updated;
} );

add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    if (/* filter 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated' is called from your cart update AJAX request */) {
        # need to calculate totals as this step was bypassed.
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        # Render your new cart HTML
        echo cart_html();
        wp_die();
    }
}, 21 );   # priority 21 so this action runs after WC_Form_Handler::update_cart_action() which runs at priority 20
```

Comment: You know, I considered "abusing" a filter near the end of the form handler, but it didn't seem right. But filtering the redirect itself would be fine, if it works! ... Thank you for this...

Comment: I actually thought of another way to do this. It also involves abusing a filter but maybe not as ugly as my original solution.

Comment: I had to abandon this whole line of reasoning because the form handler runs before Ajax actions! Therefore the cart was getting updated but my actions didn't run before it `exit`ed. So any additional tasks I had wouldn't execute. Turns out the best way to do this is attach the individual cart method (add, remove, etc) to its corresponding event listener...

Comment: It is good that you found another way. Abusing a filter is really not a good idea and should only be used as a last resort. It make code very difficult to understand as the casual reader will not expect a filter to behave in that way. I really like your idea of just refreshing the cart and not the entire page - hope you succeed.

Comment: Thanks - it's looking killer!